# django - how to unit test a post request using request.FILES

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have the following logic in my view:

```
def view_function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploadform = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if uploadform.is_valid():
            #do stuff
```

Where UploadFileForm equals to:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

I am trying to write unit tests for this view.  Looking in Django docs, the suggested way is this:

```
class test_stuffTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = django.test.client.Client()
    ...
    def test_stuff(self):
        myfile = open('....\file.csv','r')
        response = self.client.post('/', {'name':'file.csv','attachment':myfile})
        #check response
```

My goal is to get uploadform.is_valid() to evaluate to True, so I can test the code which follows the form validation.  When I run the test above, uploadform.is_valid() evaluates to False.  Is there anything I am missing?  Is the code in my test adding the file to request.FILES, or is it doing something else?

Comment: If you're not sure what is in `request.FILES`, the quickest thing to do is add add a print statement in your view to see what's going on.

Comment: hmm I tried that but the FILES argument was not included in the printout. Is there a setting to enable it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the docs, the file field is called `attachment`, but in yours, it's called `file`.

You don't need `name` in your post data either -- that refers to another field called `name`, not the name of the file that you are uploading.

Try the following:

```
def test_stuff(self): 
    myfile = open('....\file.csv','r') 
    response = self.client.post('/', {'file':myfile})
```

Answer (score 44):

The way django's testsuite does it is:

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
f = SimpleUploadedFile("file.txt", b"file_content")
```

This way you don't need to create a temp file and write to it, and you don't need to mock a file (not as easy as it sounds).

Comment: Thank you so much. 
I was trying to use Request Factory to mock the incoming file. Just placed your code replacing values and worked in the first try.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me from mocking a file! Update for Python3 django 1.10 I had to place `b` before file content, like this `f = SimpleUploadedFile("file.txt", b"file_content")` because of TypeError

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but sounds like a job for a good mock library.  I personally really like [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html).  But, I fall into the camp that believes that your unit tests should be free of all external dependencies (like having to have a file named "file.csv" in a certain location, etc.)

Comment: neat library.  Didn't know about it but will definitely take a closer look. Thanks!

Comment: It's been announced that Mock will be added to the Python's Std Library, it's probably a good thing to learn.  Here is a video by Michael Foord (original author of Mock) at last years PyCon.  http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2011-testing-with-mock-4899484  and also a video from a talk from this year's PyCon that I thought was really good.  http://pyvideo.org/video/699/testing-and-django  - I recommend checking them both out.